# Prusa i3 MK3S Z axis moving down in calibration wizard

Tags: prusa-i3, calibration, z-axis

During recalibration of my printer (due to the nozzle catching on the prints), the Z-axis went down where it used to go up, damaging the heatbed steel sheet in the process. It then failed calibration.
I didn't change the wiring since previous print although I re-adjusted the PINDA probe.
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: From the information you gave, it could have been *anything*. Some other possibilities would be the probe not working at all or the wires not working.

Answer (score 1):

*Answer taken from OP's comment*

---

the issue has been resolved (the PINDA probe was too high)

Comment: @helpme - If you care to submit your own actual answer, I will delete this Wiki answer, thanks.